# Слово "сколько" в предложении "Сколько звезд на небе!"

Tags: иноязычная-лексика

Как лучше назвать слово"сколько" при переводе с арабского в предложении "Сколько звезд на небе!" Некоторые арабисты называют вопросительной частицей ,некоторые вопросительным наречием, некоторые вопросительным словом ,хотя это предложение в арабском не вопросительное , а повествовательное ,и в конце нет вопросительного знака,а в переводе с арабского это- имя сообщительное,уважаемые филологи русского языка скажите ,пожалуйста,как это слово называется в русском и можно ли его в арабистике называть именем сообщительным ,так как в предложениях с восклицательным знаком это слово вопросительным никто из арабских ученых не называет, а все называют его именем сообщительным?

Comment: Там же чуть ниже написано, что произведения его находятся в диапазоне между верой и безбожием, от пропаганды вина и секса, до просьбы о покаянии. Впрочем, тоже самое вы увидите и в неангажированных исследованиях религиозности Хайяма на русском языке.

Вообще, к чести мусульман, в первые века своего существования они были гораздо терпимее к инакомыслию, чем христиане, поэтому и могли там развиваться такие великие деятели науки и искусства как Омар Хайям.

Comment: Вы читали Хайяма? Откройте любой сборник его стихов и прочитайте.

>Дух рабства кроется в кумирне и в Каабе,  
трезвон колоколов - язык смиренья рабий,  
и рабства черная печать равно лежит  
на четках и кресте, на церкви и Мирхабе".

Или другое

>Отречься от вина? Да это все равно,   
Что жизнь свою отдать! Чем возместишь вино?  
Могу ль я сделаться приверженцем ислама,   
Когда им высшее из благ запрещено?

Причём я не утверждаю, что он был атеистом, но праведным мусульманином назвать его тоже нельзя.

Comment: @Ищущий полез..., Все что Вам требовалась - это привести подстрочник известного всему миру рубаи - и убедить всех нас, что переводчик наврал. А бить себя пятками в грудь, уверяя, что этого не может быть потому, что не может быть никогда - смотрится плохо.   
У нас нет других биографий Хайяма, пользуемся тем, что есть. А там написано, что он неоднократно подвергался гонениям за своё вольнодумство. Да и переводы (не только на русский) говорят не в пользу его правоверной святости.  

И не кричите так, мы хорошо видим.

Comment: @Ищущий, а зачем Вы свои комментарии удалили? Некрасиво получается.

Comment: надоело все , свои тоже удалите ,только Богу известно кто он, не нам его судить...

Comment: спасиботак почему же частицы можно назвать восклицательными , а местоимение нет?

Comment: Спасибо, Людмила!Никак не могу понять по какой причине ученые вместо того, чтобы назвать эти местоимения  в восклицательных предложениях восклицательными ,говорят , что они вопросительные ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Сколько звезд на небе!"."Сколько" в школьной грамматике является вопросительно-относительным местоимением, в данном случае относительным,в книжной речи употребляется и в восклицательном предложении.  
http://orfografus.ru/index/0-46

А вообще в русском языке некоторые учёные(Ожегов в том числе) его называют определительным местоимением или определительным наречием,а кто-то местоимённым наречием.Имя сообщительное - вполне приемлемый вариант для передачи логики арабского языка.  По-моему, при переводе с арабского имеет смысл сказать: "Сколько -  имя сообщительное (в русск.яз. местоимение)"

А вот КАК является частицей, если выражает негодование, удивление и т.д.:Как! Ты опять здесь? Она как закричит!(внезапность действия).А в предложении "Как хорошо вокруг!" КАК выражает качество, это определительное наречие (= очень).В вопросит. предложении-вопросит. наречие.

Comment: Спасибо!!!

Comment: "Сколько звёзд на небе!"-предложение эллиптическое . Подлежащее СКОЛЬКО ЗВЁЗД( =много звёзд), сказуемое пропущено, можно восстановить-находится, рассыпано и т.д.

Comment: Спасибо ,значит точно не частица...

Comment: Людмила, а почему в русском не восклицательное местоимение, если уж не частица?

Comment: К счастью у Хайяма были сильные покровители. В частности, в Исхафане его покровителями были сам султан и великий визирь, правда после их смерти, учёный вынужден был покинуть город, обвинённый как раз в безбожии.

Comment: Спасибо всем,остался последний вопрос"Если это не частица , а местоимение,почему тогда нельзя назвать восклицательным местоимением?"

Comment: Что значит "нельзя". Никто не запрещает, называйте, такие попытки были в научной литературе, у Жеребило, например,группа местоименно-частичных контаминант:
http://lingvistics_dictionary.academic.ru/1998/%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5
местоимения восклицательные:1) что за! 2) какой! такой! 3) сколько! столько! 4) как! так! Но в академических грамматиках такого разряда нет, там написано, что в воскл. предложениях используются вопросит. местоимения

Answer (score 2):

Подобные слова (Как, что за, какой, сколько,где и т.п.), если они используются не для вопроса, являются восклицательными частицами и начинают собой восклицательные предложения: Какой чудесный день! Как хорошо вокруг! Что за прелесть эта Наташа! Где я только не побывал этим летом! Сколько звезд на небе!

Comment: хорошо, а если будет точка?

Comment: Ну мы же тут арабистикой не занимаемся?

Comment: как в русском будет ,если в конце будет точка? И вопрос здесь к тем кто знает , а кто не знает может не отвечать, здесь же вопрос к тем кто может и хочет помочь...

Comment: виктор1799, Вы, боюсь, не учли, что вопрос об арабском языке. ;)

Боян, конечно...

А меж обоими тельцами, - поглядите,  
- Какое множество ослов пасет аллах!   

(С)Омар Хайям

Comment: Behemothus, почему?, мне интересно как в русском будет называться, если будет точка? И вопрос читайте: "Уважаемые филологи русского языка скажите ,пожалуйста,как это слово называется в русском ...?" Я, просто, хочу знать , что вы думаете...

Comment: Уважаемый ,Behemothus ,Я вас уверяю Омар Хаййам никогда в жизни не называл ни одного единоверца ослом,это противоречит Корану ,который он знал наизусть и который я изучаю почти всю свою жизнь... Не было ни одного праведника  , который назвал бы ослом даже дурака

Comment: О те, которые уверовали! Пусть одни люди не насмехаются над другими, ведь может быть, что те лучше них. И пусть одни женщины не насмехаются над другими женщинами, ведь может быть, что те лучше них. Не обижайте самих себя (друг друга) и не называйте друг друга оскорбительными прозвищами. Скверно называться нечестивцем после того, как уверовал. А те, которые не раскаются, окажутся беззаконниками. Сура 49. аль-Худжурат «Покои»

Comment: А с чего вы решили, что в данном рубаи кого-то оскорбляют? Или ослов (животных) мало на земле? А вообще кого-кого, а Омара Хайяма называть праведным мусульманином не стоит.
>Несовместимых мы всегда полны желаний:   
В одной руке бокал, другая на Коране.  
И так вот мы живем под сводом голубым,  
Полубезбожники и полумусульмане.  

Он же

Comment: >Я вас уверяю ,Омар Хаййам никогда в жизни не называл ни одного единоверца  

Наврал переводчик?

Comment: >Я вас уверяю ,Омар Хаййам никогда в жизни не называл ни одного единоверца   

Вы его лично знали?  

>Наврал переводчик?  

Ну да. Он типа, взялся переводить с арабского - и с ужасом обнаружил, что Хайям писал на фарси. ;) К тому же был великим грешником ;)

